# Editando dados com Angular e php

Tags: php, angularjs

Alguém sabe como selecionar um dado e ir para uma tela de edição, usando html, angularJS e php?

Exemplo:
Tenho uma lista de contatos.
Quero fazer um botão que guarda o id desse contato e quando eu clicar, nesse botão, ele me leva para uma outra página html onde eu possa fazer a edição dos dados desse contato.

Tenho isso:

```
<a href="editar.html?id={{usuario.id}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Editar</a>
```

E funciona. Sou direcionado para o editar.html e com o id na url:

> localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/Cadastro_AngularJS/editar.html?id=1

Nessa página tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module("myCrud", []);

angular.module("myCrud").controller("myCrudCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    var carregarUsuario = function () {
        $http.get("php/buscaPEdicao.php", {params: {id: usuario}}).success(function (data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.usuarios = data;
        });
    };
    carregarUsuario();
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="myCrudCtrl">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Password</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="usuario.newName">{{usuario.name}}</td>                       
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="usuario.newEmail">{{usuario.email}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="usuario.newPass">{{usuario.pass}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

E meu php:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];

$usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$return = array();

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
     array_push($return, $dados);
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Tem algum código para adicionar na pergunta?

Comment: Não @rray...
Fiz só o botão com link para a página que vou criar.

Comment: O problema é `$_GET['id']` nunca está setado?

Comment: @rray, primeiro tirei o ponto de exclamação e não adiantou.
Depois tirei todo o if e também não funcionou.

Comment: Como podes ver @rray, alterei o $_GET['id'] para $_POST['id'] e fiz um teste pelo postman e o id vem setado.

Comment: Você está chamando o método **carregarUsuario** sem passar o parâmetro **usuario**.

Comment: @Daniel, na verdade o que eu fiz tá errado, não se passa parâmetro.

Comment: Mas de onde vem o **usuario** do `{id: usuario}`?

Comment: Pois é, vi uns vídeos e tem gente que coloca id como parâmetro.
Mas e depois? Pois coloco usuario como parâmetro e nada muda.
Tens conhecimento de angular @Daniel?

Comment: Amigo deixa eu ver se eu entendi, você está tendo dificuldade na hora de buscar as informações do usuário ao fazer a requisição para 'php/buscaPEdicao.php' ?

Comment: Exatamente @Mathdesigner47.

Comment: Mas qual a sua dúvida, tente ser mais específico, em quais pontos você está tendo dificuldade?

Comment: Entendo sim, vou colocar uma resposta aqui.

Comment: @Mathdesigner47, é o seguinte:
Tenho uma tela, em html, onde eu cadastro contatos.
Nessa mesma tela tenho um botão com link para outro arquivo html onde eu tenho que buscar do banco, apenas o dado do contato selecionado, que eu passo o id pelo botão do link.
Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer os dados, desse contato, aparecerem nessa outra página em html, entendeu?
Caso ainda não tenha entendido, escreva para gustavo.msevero@gmail.com, ou acesse o meu git com os arquivos https://github.com/GugaSevero/CRUD_AngularJS

Comment: @GustavoSevero agora eu entendi, vou escrever uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Segue abaixo um exemplo, acredito que seja isso que esteja tentando fazer. Abraço.

```js
angular.module("myCrud", ["ngResource"]);

angular.module("myCrud").controller("myCrudCtrl", function ($scope, $resource) {
   //resUsuario = $resource("/yourUrl");
   $scope.current_user = {};
   $scope.users = [];
   $scope.users.push({id: 1, name: "AAA"});
   $scope.users.push({id: 2, name: "BBB"});
   $scope.users.push({id: 3, name: "CCC"});
  
   $scope.setCurrentUser = function(user) {
     $scope.current_user = user;
     
    // Usando o $resource para chamar uma API
    // resUsuario.get({user_id: user.id}).then(function doSomething(response) {
    //   $scope.current_user = response;
    // });
   };
  
   $scope.save = function(user) {
     alert("Usar '$http' e fazer o seu post do objeto 'current_user'");
     
     // Usando o $resource para chamar uma API
     //resUsuario.save($scope.current_user).then(function doSomething(res){
     //  console.log("salvo com sucesso");
     //});
   };
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myCrud">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-resource.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCrudCtrl">
  <h2>LIST</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td ng-bind="user.id"></td>
      <td ng-bind="user.name"></td>
      <td><button type="button" ng-click="setCurrentUser(user)">edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  

  <h2>FORM</h2>
  <form ng-submit="save()">
    <div>
      <label>ID</label>
      <input ng-model="current_user.id" disabled></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>NAME</label>
      <input ng-model="current_user.name"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>salvar</button>
    </div>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Conseguiu testar?

Answer (score 0):

Coloque seu código da seguinte forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module("myCrud", []);

angular.module("myCrud").controller("myCrudCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

    var carregarUsuario = function () {
        //mudei de 'get' para 'post'
        $http.post("php/buscaPEdicao.php", {id: usuario}).success(function (data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.usuarios = data;
        });
    };
    carregarUsuario();
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="myCrudCtrl">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>Password</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="usuario in usuarios">
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="usuario.newName">{{usuario.name}}</td>                       
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="usuario.newEmail">{{usuario.email}}</td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="usuario.newPass">{{usuario.pass}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

E no código php fica assim

```
<?php
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_dencode($post);
$id = $json['id'];


$usuario = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'");

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$return = array();

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($usuario)) {
     array_push($return, $dados);
}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Comment: Dica: as respostas que costumam receber votos são as que explicam *porquê* o código resolve o problema.